# GSL Random number generator in C

Tags: c, memory, random, gsl

I'm trying to use the random number generator from the GSL.
In my code I have something like

```
...
gsl_rng * r;  /* global generator for Random Numbers*/

void init_rand_generator( int seed ){
    /* Random numbers initialization */
    const gsl_rng_type * T;
    gsl_rng_env_setup();
    gsl_rng_default_seed = seed;
    T = gsl_rng_default;
    r = gsl_rng_alloc( T );    

}
...
```

The problem is that, when I call the `init_rand_generator( seed )` function from another function, in order to use `gsl_rng_uniform( r )`, the memory blows up and my system hangs.
However, when I initialize the random number variables in the function where I use the `gsl_rng_uniform( r )` function, everything works fine.
I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: That sounds like you've got an unintended unterminated recursion. Check whether, eg, gsl_rng_env_setup() is calling init_rand_generator(). A debugger is a useful tool... or analyzing a coredump may give you similar information about what's calling what calling what.

Comment: HOWEVER: What's setting gsl_rng_default before you assign it to T? A bad pointer there could ruin your whole day...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. According to the documentation `This function reads the environment variables GSL_RNG_TYPE and GSL_RNG_SEED and uses their values to set the corresponding library variables gsl_rng_default and gsl_rng_default_seed` . Maybe, as you said, when I do `gsl_rng_default_seed = seed`, it is trying to read the seed from the same function :/

Comment: Actually, I found the problem. In a function I was calling other function which had also `init_rand_generator( seed )` and it produced an infinite recursion. Thanks for pointing that out, I could not figure that out before.